# Застенчивый - при чем тут стенка?

Tags: этимология

Застенчивый человек - стеснительный, скромный. Но, если разобраться в этом слове, получается интересно: "за-стенчивый". То есть, за стеной.
То есть, выходит, что застенчивый - это тот, кто сидит за стенкой (сосед?) ))))? Или же тот, кто держится за стенку (пьяный?) ))))? Или тут совершенно другой смысл?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Откуда вы взяли такой странный глагол: "застенчивать"?

Comment: Вообще-то, это описка. С Вами не бывает?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**застенчивый**

```
Искон. Суф. производное от *застеняться* — «загораживаться» (исходное слово *застень* «что или кто застит» < *стень* «тень»). См. *тень, стена.* Застенчивый буквально — «загораживающийся, прячущийся» (от незнакомых).
```

*Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа. Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва. 2004.*

http://etymological.academic.ru/1379

Answer (score 2):

Домашний, стеснительный - стеснен четырьмя стенами, трус, скромный (вспомните русское кром - хоромы - укромный (куча слов), пугливый, осторожный, недоверчивый, нерешительный, стыдливый, робкий, боязливый.
Психологически - боязнь нового, непонятного, неисследованного на своем личном опыте, в следствии долгой изоляции.
Слово стесняться от тесно, что в свою очередь идет от тесать, тес. То есть обработанное бревно. Ныне тесом и доски называют. Из отесанных бревен делают стены, которые, ну, конечно, бросают тень. Иногда.

Но это тень на плетень.

Для справки:

Тесный

тесный те́сный те́сен, тесна́, те́сно, укр. тíсний, тíсно, др.-русск. тѣснъ, ст.-слав. тѣснъ στενός (Зогр., Мар., Супр.; см. Вондрак, Aksl. Gr. 186), болг. те́сен, сербохорв. тиjѐсан, -сна, ти̏jесни "тесный, узкий", местн. н. Ти̏jесно, словен. tẹ́sǝn, tẹ́sna, чеш. těsný, слвц. tesný, польск. сiаsnу, в.-луж. ćěsny, н.-луж. śěsny. Из *těsknъ, родственного ти́скать, возм., сюда же те́сто (см. Брандт, РФВ 25, 28; Вондрак, там же; Брюкнер 60). •• [Махек (LР, 5, 1955, стр. 69) пытается сблизить слав. těsnъ с греч. στενός "узкий, тесный". – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Сами "реконструкции" от авторов, ничего собственно, кроме их личного мнения не выражают.
Их нет в языке, а значит, выдумка.
Попытка внедрить выдумку, навязывание "новояза". А оно надо? Вопрос - кому?

застенчив-стена, а она от тени, а тень?